# How can I compare two 2D arrays? In javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, 2d

I have a problem to compare two 2D arrays in javascript.
It should output "true" if the two 2D arrays are the same.

The code I tried:

`

```
function check(){
   
    if (data.every() === solution.every()){
        alert("example");
    } else {
        console.log("Data Array: " + data);
        console.log("Solution Array: " + solution);
    }
  
}
```

`

I think my solution only works with two 1D arrays. I hope someone can help me and teach me something.

Note: I only use jquery and nativ js.

Thanks in advance.

~Luca

Comment: Thats not how `every` works, `every` takes a function. Further on `every` returns a boolean. So you would just compare 2 booleans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume something like this would work :

```
function test(array1, array2)
{
 if(array1.length !== array2.length) return false;

for(let i=0;i<array1.length;i++)
{
 if(array1[i].length !== array2[i].length) return false;
 for(let j=0;j<array1[i].length;j++)
 {
  if(array1[i][j] !== array2[i][j]) return false;
 }
}
return true;
}
```

You could also do a recursive version that would work for array of N-dimensions, but it you need only 2, the above is fine.

Comment: Thanks ! It works fine, but now my alert("exmaple"); gets outputed 4 times.

Comment: Are you stilll using every ? Because you shouldn't. Just do if(test(data,solution)) alert('Example');

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for any number of dimensions:

```js
const random2dArray = (n,m) => Array(n).fill(0)
  .map(_=>Array(m).fill(0).map(_=>10*Math.random()|0))

const arrEq = (a,b) => Array.isArray(a) ?
  a.length===b.length && a.every((e,i)=>arrEq(e,b[i])) : a===b

const a = random2dArray(3,3)
const b = random2dArray(3,3)
const c = random2dArray(3,5)
const d = random2dArray(6,7)
const e = structuredClone(a)

console.log(arrEq(a,b))
console.log(arrEq(a,c))
console.log(arrEq(a,d))
console.log(arrEq(a,e))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this requirement by following below steps **:**

- `flatten` both the 2D arrays into a 1D array.
- Check the length of both the arrays along with the each item check using [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const data = [[1,2,3], [4,5]];
const solution = [[1,2,3], [4,5]];

const res = (data.flat().length === solution.flat().length) && data.flat().every((item, index) => item === solution.flat()[index]);

console.log(res ? 'Both arrays are equal' : 'not equal');
```

Answer (score -1):

A common solution that many people suggest is to use JSON.stringify(). This allows us to serialize each array and then compare the two serialized strings. A simple implementation of this might look something like this:

```
function check(){
   
    if ( JSON.stringify(data) === JSON.stringify(solution) ){
        alert("example");
    } else {
        console.log("Data Array: " + data);
        console.log("Solution Array: " + solution);
    }
}
```

Comment: It will convert the whole array,if the first element is not the same,still need to convert

Comment: I am doubtful many (if any) professional developers would advocate for this approach. This seems incredibly inefficient on multiple levels. Serializing data is expensive in terms of both time and memory.  Depending on the size of the structure, we may need to allocate a massive buffer for the output. This would break if there are any circular dependencies. And finally, we can't actually guarantee that the two strings will be the same since the JSON field order is not guaranteed to be the same even if they contain the same fields.